# Check and match with a list of String and replace with a certain value

Tags: java

I do have some random message like...

```
Please conform to regex ^[0-9]*$ with a maximum length of 13
Please conform to regex ^[a-z]*$ 
Please conform to regex (?:\\d*\\.)?\\d+ with a maximum length of 999
(and many more...)
```

How to replace those regex string with

```
'Only number' when '^[0-9]*$' appears 
'Only lower case' when '^[a-z]*$'appears
(and so on... ?)
```

Comment: So you want to match strings that represent regular expressions in your messages, then replace the regex Strings with a human readable description of what the regex does?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have `String str = "...";`. You can use the following `String` class methods:

```
if(str.contains("somethingYouWantReplaced")
    str.replace("somethingYouWantReplaced", "newValue");
```

Also, check out:

Check out [String.ReplaceAll(String Regex, String replacement)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

Comment: I don't know which regex will come. but I know...
 ^[0-9]$ will be replaced by Only Number;
^[a-z]$  : will be replaced by Only lower case;